# passenger count vs passenger number

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I dreamed up these sentences. Are there any differences between "passenger count" and "passenger number" in terms of usage and meaning?

> Beijing's subway has the largest annual **passenger number** in the
> country.

> Beijing's subway has the largest annual **passenger count** in the
> country.

> The island’s total **visitor number** increased by 1 million.

> The island’s total **visitor count** increased by 1 million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Passenger number" and "visitor number" aren't really correct here. "Number of passengers" or "number of visitors" would be correct - i.e., would have the same meaning as "passenger count" and "visitor count," respectively.

"Passenger number," for instance, sounds like a specific number assigned to a passenger - like, a number printed on the passenger's ticket or something.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What if I use the plural "passenger numbers"? Does it mean the same as "passenger count"?

Comment: Hmm, that might actually get you a little closer, but still isn't quite right. "Numbers" sounds to me like a somewhat uncertain/inexact amount in this context. You might say, for instance, "the visitor numbers have gone up" and that would mean a general increase. My gut feeling is you wouldn't, however, say "the total visitor numbers increased by X," because in that case you have X, the exact amount.

Comment: Thanks again. But I found many examples that say passenger numbers have gone up by x%. Can you open this link? https://ludwig.guru/s/passenger+numbers

Comment: _Passenger numbers_ seems fine to me.

Comment: Yeah, see, most of those examples in the link are pretty vague. With the percentage maybe it sounds ok, even though that's a bit clearer in amount, but you're still left wondering (sometimes) what the % even means - passengers who travelled at all, even once? Total trips? How are round-trips counted? So I feel like the plural "numbers" is more often used when there is some lack of detail. The following would sound weird to me: "Passenger numbers increased by 4,328."